# How can i force Windows to start my own MSI after .NET installation performs a reboot?

Tags: .net, windows, wix, windows-installer

I have a program which requires .NET 4.7.2.
Therefore i created a bootstrapper which downloads .NET and install
it. Unfortunately the installtion requires a reboot.
My question is how can i tell Windows to start my MSI after the reboot
of the .NET installtion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a registry value under the [Run keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SetupApi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) for this, with a command line for msiexec to launch your package.

However, this should be handled automatically by most [[setup authoring tools][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482833/are-visual-studio-setup-projects-suitable-for-complex-setups)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482833/are-visual-studio-setup-projects-suitable-for-complex-setups). What tool are you using to build your setup?

**EDIT:** Here are two related topics on handling this when building packages with Wix Toolset:

- [How can I continue the installation from the point it left due to reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263010/how-can-i-continue-the-installation-from-the-point-it-left-due-to-reboot)
- [WiX Burn after restart/force reboot continuing installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166186/wix-burn-after-restart-force-reboot-continuing-installation)

Comment: I'm using WIX for the creation of the setup.